# Determine ANSI_DEFAULTS setting ON or OFF?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, configuration, connections, session

How can I determine if ANSI_DEFAULTS is enabled or not on my server. My server is using IMPLICIT transactions and one way from which it can affect it based on setting of ANSI_DEFAULTS.

How can I determine state of ANSI_DEFAULTS?

Comment: You'd think DBCC USEROPTIONS would provide IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS, but nope.  Thanks for your answer @solomon-rutzky!

Answer (score 3):

`ANSI_DEFAULTS` isn't really a distinct option, but a logical grouping of several other session-based options:

1. IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS
2. CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT
3. ANSI_WARNINGS
4. ANSI_PADDING
5. ANSI_NULLS
6. QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
7. ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON

You can use the [@@OPTIONS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177525.aspx) configuration function to get the bit-masked value of the current Session settings, the values of which are noted on the [Configure the user options Server Configuration Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190763.aspx) MSDN page.

Putting those elements together gets you the following query which determines the current session setting of the "ansi_defaults" group of options:

```
SELECT @@OPTIONS AS [user_options],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 2 = 2 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [implicit_transactions],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 4 = 4 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [cursor_close_on_commit],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 8 = 8 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [ansi_warnings],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 16 = 16 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [ansi_padding],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 32 = 32 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [ansi_nulls],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 256 = 256 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [quoted_identifier],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 1024 = 1024 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [ansi_null_dflt_on],
       -- all above options combined
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 1342 = 1342 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [ansi_defaults]
```

When *all* of the base options are set to `ON`, then `ANSI_DEFAULTS` will be shown as being `ON`. If *any* of those options is `OFF`, then `ANSI_DEFAULTS` will also be `OFF`. You can see this behavior via the following test:

```
SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON;

DBCC USEROPTIONS; -- ansi_defaults is SET

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;

DBCC USEROPTIONS; -- ansi_nulls AND ansi_defaults are missing

SET ANSI_NULLS ON;

DBCC USEROPTIONS; -- ansi_nulls AND ansi_defaults are back
```

Setting `ANSI_DEFAULTS` to `ON` will set *all* of those options to `ON`. Likewise, setting `ANSI_DEFAULTS` to `OFF` will set *all* of those options to `OFF`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [DBCC USER Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180065.aspx) to find..DBCC userOptions displays only values that are set.If you are not able to find any setting here,that means it is not set

```
SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON;  
GO  
-- Display the current settings.  
DBCC USEROPTIONS;  
GO  
-- SET ANSI_DEFAULTS OFF.  
SET ANSI_DEFAULTS OFF;  
GO
```

---Output:

```
textsize    2147483647
language    us_english
dateformat  mdy
datefirst   7
lock_timeout    -1
quoted_identifier   SET
arithabort  SET
ansi_null_dflt_on   SET
ansi_defaults   SET
ansi_warnings   SET
ansi_padding    SET
ansi_nulls  SET
concat_null_yields_null SET
cursor_close_on_commit  SET
implicit_transactions   SET
isolation level read committed
```

Comment: The setting in question is ANSI_DEFAULTS, which is server side setting not ANSI_NULLS.

Comment: i mistook it for set ansi_nulls ,please see updated answer

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. On another note I can see one of my open transaction which is IMPLICIT transaction, It is open since so long. Now I am not able to understand how and who enabled this Implicit transaction. Anyway I can find out.